# Picklist refresh taking long time for European Users

Tags: apex, picklist

We have three picklists in Case object (Queue/Type/Area).

Queue drives Type...Type drives Area.

This picklist refresh for Type and Area is quite fast (1-2 secs for users in Asia & Americas) while it is very slow for European users (7-9 secs).

When I proxy login via UI as an EU user (I am physically present in Asia) I don't see this issue.

But when I login to our London VPN i am able to observe the delay in the dependent picklist refresh.

Can someone tell me what could be causing this issue ?

Comment: What is the domain for your org? If we knew that, we could help you. For example, is your org on NA15, EU2, AP3, etc? That, combined with some understanding of your VPN, would explain things.
You see, for a given org, there is no real concept of an EU user vs APAC user, even when doing a proxy login, unless you have some special setup for access.

This is a valid question, so please do not put on hold - it could help lots of multinational companies understand how Service Delivery works.

Comment: Having said that, there could be other things at play, including the refresh depending on some sharing settings in the org. We've seen this for some of Salesforce's largest customers in the past.
Are you using Event Monitoring to see where the hold-up is in the system?